# Pandas: How to sum particular rows

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Suppose I have a Pandas DataFrame which looks like this:

```
category  sentences
Data1     String1
NaN       String2
NaN       String3
Data2     String1
NaN       String4
Data2     String1
NaN       String6
NaN       String7
Data3     String1
NaN       String8
NaN       String9
```

I want to convert it something like this:

```
category  sentences
Data1     String1 String2 String3
Data2     String1 String4
Data2     String1 String6 String7
Data3     String1 String8 String9
```

As you can see from headers, right column is sentences of full dialogues and left column is their respective categories. What I'm trying to do here is simply select the rows with `NaN` values and add up to their preceding ones until it reaches `String1`.

So far, it's been a failure for me as I tried different stuff and still no solution. How can I do that?

Another question: I select my DataFrame (let's call that `df`) and selected first 3 row and summed them using `df[0:3].sum()` which returns `Series([], dtype: float64)`. If I add `.sum(axis=1)` at the end, all I got is zero on each row. I tried `.sum(axis=0)` and it returned `Series([], dtype: float64)`. I also tried adding `iloc` as well but got same results. So, anyone can tell what I'm doing wrong and what I'm supposed to do?

**TL;DR:** I want to add up strings to each other from `String1` to `String1`, without including the last `String1`. Is it possible to do that and if so, how?

*just a little note: Sorry about the formatting. I still couldn't get used to it...*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firt create `Series` by unique values from `arange` with `ffill` ([`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.fillna.html) with method='ffill') where are replaced [`notnull`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.notnull.html) values of `category`:

```
s = df['category'].where(df['category'].isnull(), np.arange(len(df.index))).ffill()
0     0
1     0
2     0
3     3
4     3
5     5
6     5
7     5
8     8
9     8
10    8
Name: category, dtype: int64
```

Then [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) by `s` and [`agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.aggregate.html):

```
df = df.groupby(s).agg({'sentences':','.join, 'category':'first'}).reset_index(drop=True)
print (df)
  category                sentences
0    Data1  String1,String2,String3
1    Data2          String1,String4
2    Data2  String1,String6,String7
3    Data3  String1,String8,String9
```

Comment: Thank you! Worked like a charm. Just a little followup question if you don't mind: why did you use `'first'` in `'category':'first'`?

Comment: because it is first value per group, groups are created by `s`, because need distinguish same values of `category` column.

Comment: I see. Thanks again for helping a newbie!

Comment: No problem, every of us starts. If know, I am glad can help ;) Nice day!

Answer (score 1):

It is non-optimum, non-pythonic and ugly! but it does the job:

```
import pandas as pd

old_table = pd.read_csv('your_table.csv')
new_table = pd.DataFrame([],columns=('category','sentences'))

for ID,row in old_table.iterrows():
    if not pd.isnull(row['category']):
        new_table.loc[len(new_table)] = [row['category'],[row['sentences']]]
    else:
        string = list(new_table.loc[len(new_table)-1]['sentences'])
        string.append(row['sentences'])
        new_table.loc[len(new_table)-1]['sentences'] = string

print(old_table,'\n====\n',new_table)
```

it gives:

```
  category sentences
0      One     hello
1      NaN        my
2      NaN    little
3      NaN    friend
4      Two     hello
5      NaN        to
6      NaN       you
7      NaN       too 
====
   category                    sentences
0      One  [hello, my, little, friend]
1      Two        [hello, to, you, too]
```

Comment: Thanks! This one works too, except I have to join lists in each row. But as you said, it works.

Also, a quick correction: I believe it should be `pd.read_csv`, if I'm not mistaken.

Answer (score 1):

Create a temporary ID column to be used as a group key along with category column and then concat the sentences for each group.

```
df=df.copy()
df['ID'] = df.index.to_series()[df.category.notnull()]
df.fillna(method='ffill')\
  .groupby(['ID','category'])['sentences']\
  .apply(lambda x: ' '.join(x))\
  .reset_index()\
  .drop('ID',1)
Out[59]: 
  category                sentences
0    Data1  String1 String2 String3
1    Data2          String1 String4
2    Data2  String1 String6 String7
3    Data3  String1 String8 String9
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! But unfortunately, it gives me following error:

`SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead`

Comment: That's a warning message and can be a false alarm sometimes. To get rid of it, you can do a df=df.copy() first before you run the code.